# Как поменять clusterIconLayout у конкретной кластеризованной метки?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как поменять clusterIconLayout у конкретной кластеризованной метки (или ее overlay) при возникновении события balloonopen, не меняя при этом clusterIconLayout  у всей коллекции в objectManager?

Comment: меня пресет на конкретном объекте: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_events вот пример

Comment: Спасибо, способ     objectManager.clusters.setClusterOptions(clusterId, { preset: 'islands#blueHomeCircleIcon'});    действительно рабочий! А как правильно синтаксически написать, чтобы менялся не preset, а собственный SVG - objectManager.clusters.setClusterOptions(clusterId, {clustericonImageHref: 'images/svg/my.svg'}) ?